# PrestaShop unwanted part of URL added

Tags: prestashop

I have this issue here, where the title of the site has an additional " title=" added to the URL, whereas the picture leads to the correct URL. I'm not really familiar with PrestaShop so perhaps you would know where to start looking?[the URL from the title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZaHn.png)

[The URL from the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Pp9.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one HTML attribute is not closed properly.
That title is a separate attribute, like this:

```
<a href="mylink" title="The title of the link"> LINK </a>
```

It is possible that only one quotation mark is missing.

Check the 'catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl'